# effective_end_date not 31-dec-4712 in sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table tab_assignment_xx

```
date_from   date_end     action  person_number
01-Apr-2014 31-Jul-2014   HIRE   050498
01-Aug-2014 31-Jan-2015   OTHERS    050498
01-Feb-2015 30-Jun-2015   OTHERS    050498
01-Jul-2015 15-Nov-2015   OTHERS    050498
16-Nov-2015 31-Dec-2015 OTHERS  050498
01-Jan-2016 30-JAN-2016 OTHERS  050498

01-APR-2016  31-JUL-2016   hire    83982
01-jan-2015  31-dec-4712   Others   6447
```

Now i want to check for all those particular employees with effective_start_date and effective_End_date that it should have 31-dec-4712 as `max(effective_end_date)` for example : for 050498 the max(effective_end_date) is not '31-dec-4712' and same goes for 83982. 6447 is correct.

for this i made :

```
  select * from (
    select T.*,
      max(EFFECTIVE_START_DATE) over (partition by PERSON_NUMBER order by EFFECTIVE_START_DATE) MAX_FROM
    from  tab_assignment_xx T
    where 1=1
    --T.PERSON_NUMBER = '093343'
    AND ASSIGNMENT_TYPE='E'
  )
  where MAX_FROM <> to_date('31-DEC-4712')
;
```

But this is not working in the sense that it is both the rows with and without 31-dec-4712 max eff end date

Comment: Are you getting an error? A different result set than expected?  Be specific how this is not working.

Comment: "Not working" is not really helpful, does it return a wrong result set? Remove the `order by EFFECTIVE_START_DATE` which results in a `RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` default.

Comment: Thanks you two :)
Have updated. It is returning both the record even without 31-dec-4712

Comment: What data type are those date fields?  Your where clause seems to treat them as strings, but your `MAX` implies it's already a date.

Comment: @Mr.Llama- Nice observation. Changedi t still the same error. gettign records with effective end date '31-dec-4712'

Comment: I see ** in the date_end field? Isn't date_end string and not of type date?

Comment: its date. I tried using the bold type in the question edit section but that added **

Comment: Did you remove the `order by EFFECTIVE_START_DATE` and still get wrong rows?

Comment: yes dnoeth still getting the 31-dec-4712 for few rows

Comment: You should remove the ORDER BY and your MAX_FROM is not correct, because according to your data, you'll never have a start_date = 31-dec-4712. You should test with your end_date.

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( date_from, date_end, action, person_number ) AS
SELECT DATE '2014-04-01', DATE '2014-07-31', 'HIRE',   '050498' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2014-08-01', DATE '2015-01-31', 'OTHERS', '050498' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2015-02-01', DATE '2015-06-30', 'OTHERS', '050498' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2015-07-01', DATE '2015-11-15', 'OTHERS', '050498' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2015-11-16', DATE '2015-12-31', 'OTHERS', '050498' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2016-01-01', DATE '2016-01-30', 'OTHERS', '050498' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2016-04-01', DATE '2016-07-31', 'hire',   '83982'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2015-01-01', DATE '4712-12-31', 'Others', '6447'   FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT Date_From, Date_To, action, person_number
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         MAX( date_end )
           OVER ( PARTITION BY person_number
                  ORDER BY ROWNUM
                  ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
                ) AS mx
  FROM   table_name t
)
WHERE mx <> DATE '4712-12-31';
```

**Output**:

```
DATE_FROM           DATE_END            ACTION PERSON_NUMBER
------------------- ------------------- ------ -------------
2014-04-01 00:00:00 2014-07-31 00:00:00 HIRE   050498        
2014-08-01 00:00:00 2015-01-31 00:00:00 OTHERS 050498        
2015-02-01 00:00:00 2015-06-30 00:00:00 OTHERS 050498        
2015-07-01 00:00:00 2015-11-15 00:00:00 OTHERS 050498        
2015-11-16 00:00:00 2015-12-31 00:00:00 OTHERS 050498        
2016-01-01 00:00:00 2016-01-30 00:00:00 OTHERS 050498        
2016-04-01 00:00:00 2016-07-31 00:00:00 hire   83982
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check if this works(I din't try). Comment if anything wrong.

```
 select * from tab_assignment_xx a where to_date('31-DEC-4712')<>(select max(date_end) from tab_assignment_xx b where a.person_number=b.person_number);
```